# A delayed package install skips Post Install Script

Tags: managed-package, postinstall, install

After installing our package 10 times, it timed out installing twice and said it would email me with details of the install. It eventually installed after a few more minutes and emailed, but there was no easy way to access the Post Install Script without finding it under the installed packages settings.

Is there a better way to expose the user to the Post Install Script when an install takes too long?

Comment: FWIW, we just ended up adding a note to our help document explaining what to do when this happened. I would still be glad to hear of a better way.